# Given $G$ group and $a \in G$ , $a^n = e$, $\gcd(m,n) = 1$, prove $\exists b \in G $ that $a = b^m$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, discrete-mathematics

Given $G$ group and $a \in G$ , $a^n = e$, $\gcd(m,n) = 1$, prove that $\exists b \in G $ that $a = b^m$.

Well, I'm not sure how to approach this, any hints are welcomed.

Comment: Hint: there exist integers $r$ and $s$ such that $rm + sn = 1$. So $a^1 = \dots$

Comment: More generally, if $a$ and $c$ commute, and $a^n = c^m$, then there exists $b$ such that $a = b^m$ and $c = b^n$.

Comment: Proof: with $r$ and $s$ as in Alex Macedo's comment, put $b = a^rc^s$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\,\ \gcd(m,n) = 1\,\Rightarrow\,{\large \frac{1}m}\bmod n\,$ exists $\,\Rightarrow \left[\,\color{#c00}a^{\Large\color{#c00}{ \frac{1}m}\!\bmod n} \right]^{\large\underset{\LARGE\, m}{\phantom{1}}}\! = a\ $

**Remark**  $ $ Thus the solution of $\ b^m = a\ $ is simply $\ b = \color{#c00}{a^{\large \frac{1}m}},\, $ just like in $\,\Bbb R$

Comment: We used  $\, j\equiv k\pmod n\,\Rightarrow\, a^{\large j} = a^{\large k}\,$ by $\,a^n = 1,\,$ i.e. exponents on $\,a\,$ can be interpretd mod $n$ $\quad$

Comment: Thanks, what if $o(a) = 218$, what will be the result of $o(a^{63})$? can I use what we proved here on this?

Comment: @Ilan $\ a^{\large 63k}=1\,\Rightarrow\, 218\mid 63k.\ $ What does this imply about $k$ given $\,\gcd(218,63) = 1?\ \ $

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure sir. ):

Comment: @Ilan Apply [Euclid's Lemma.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1162403/242)

Comment: I understood nothing from what you wrote there. :(

Comment: Maybe $k$ needs to be $218$?

Comment: because then $a^{{(218)}63} =e^{63} = e$

Comment: @Ilan yes, since $218,63$ are coprime, $\,218\mid 63k\,\Rightarrow\,218\mid k\,$ By Euclid's Lemma, or by FTA, or by gcd properties, etc.

Comment: I see. so $o(a^{63}) = o(a) = 218$

Comment: @Ilan Exactly $\phantom{}$

Answer (score 1):

Due to gcd($m,n$)=1, $\exists$ $c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$ $|$ $1=cm+dn$ $\Rightarrow$ $a^1=a^{cm+dn} \Rightarrow a^{cm+dn}=a^{cm}a^{dn}=(a^{c})^m (a^n)^{d}=(a^c)^m e^d=(a^c)^m$.

Now, define as $b:=a^c$, and that's all!!

Comment: **Note** $\  c = {\large \frac{1}m}\bmod n\ $ so it's $\ \left(a^{\Large \frac{1}m}\right)^m\! = a\ $ with exponents interpreted mod $n,\,$ see my answer.

Comment: I don't get it... Could you explain yourself?

Comment: The point is that the solution of $\ b^m = a\ $ is simply $\ b = a^{\large \frac{1}m},\, $ just like in $\,\Bbb R.$  The Bezout computations obfuscate  this key idea.

Answer (score 1):

Since $gcd(m,n)=1\implies$ by Bezout's Lemma, $\exists x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $mx+ny=1$.

So $a=a^1=a^{mx+ny}=(a^x)^m.(a^n)^y=(a^x)^m$.

Choose $b=a^x$.

Comment: **Note** $\  x = {\large \frac{1}m}\bmod n\ $ so it's $\ \left(a^{\Large \frac{1}m}\right)^m\! = a\ $ with exponents interpreted mod $n,\,$ see my answer.

Comment: This is perfect @seeker. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Since $a^n=e$, then $G$ is a cyclic group generated by a. If $(m,n) = 1$,then $(-m,n)=1$ and $a^{-m}$ is another generator of the group $G$. Denote $k := -m$.

For the proof, suppose by contradiction. Suppose that $a^k$ is not a generator of $G$. So, the order of the element $a^k$ is not $n$, i. e. there exists a natural number $n_1 < n$ such that $({a^k})^{n_1}=a^{kn_1}=e$. Since the order of the element $a$ is $n$, then $kn_1=nq$ and since $(n,k)=1$, then $n\mid n_1$, i. e. $n_1\ge n$. This is a contradiction and as a result $a^k$ is a generator of the group $G$: $a^k=a^{-m}=b$, i. e. $b^m=a$. Choose $b = a^{-m}$.

Comment: For answers, and in general, you should use LaTeX formatting! This is highly unreadable!