# Simple divisiblity problem and gcd

Tags: divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Let n be be positive integer such that $n=\frac{pb}{q}$ for some prime number $p$ and for some integers $b$ and $q$. Let's also assume that $gcd(p,q)=1$. Show that $p|n$.

My attempt:

Since $n$ is positive integer we have that $q|pb$ and since $p$ and $q$ are relativity prime we have that $q|b$ so $\frac{b}{q}=a$, where $a$ is some integer. So we have that $n=ap$ and this ends the proof.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Your proof is fine. Alternatively, $nq=pb$ implies $p$ divides $n$ because $\gcd(p,q)=1$.

Comment: $\ (p,q)=1,\ p\mid qn\Rightarrow p\mid n\ $ follows by [Euclid's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1162403/242) in the linked dupe. Note $\,n/p = b/q\,$ so $\,p\mid n\iff q\mid b\ \ $